# Font Picker select box with previews

Tags: css, select, drop-down-menu, fonts, picker

I have an online logo maker tool, and I want to give users the option to choose a font from a selection of about 100 free web fonts I have collected.

The best way to do this would be in a form select box, where each font was displayed as an option in the select, see example:

[image: example]

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to achieve this using CSS, so I have been looking at 3rd party plugins.

I found a very nice script by Bootstrap Form Helper which lets you display [a select box of the user's device fonts](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/font/), and one which displays [a selection of Google Web Fonts as a select box](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/googlefont/), but neither of these quite fit my purpose. (The fonts are not on the users device, or hosted by Google).

I want to do exactly the same thing, but with a list of ".ttf" files from my server, for example:

```
[
  "Alakob"     : "http://www.example.com/fonts/Alakob.ttf",
  "Baron Neue" : "http://www.example.com/fonts/Baron-Neue.ttf",
  "Casper"     : "http://www.example.com/fonts/Casper.ttf",
  "Damion"     : "http://www.example.com/fonts/Damion-Regular.ttf",
  ...
]
```

Does anyone know if either of these scripts could be amended to display a list of font files I provide as a JSON or XML feed, rather than the fonts on the user's device, or from Google font?

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Sorry, I have already found a resource which does about 90% of what I want, I just wanted to know if it is possible to amend it do display fonts stored locally on the web server.